# Next page by PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, r, phantomjs

I would like to crawl all links href from `https://www.vietnamworks.com/job-search/all-jobs`.

[image]

I realized the website used javascript to render content, so I used phantomjs in R to crawl, but I can only crawl page 1st.

[image]

How I can click next page and crawl all rest links.

Comment: Get ID of button and execute onclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the data is what you are after...there is another way to accomplish this. If you right click on the page in chrome and inspect the network calls you can find the API calls the site is making to retrieve the data itself. Each call results in 50 results and it would appear maxed at 5000 results total, so max-page param in function would be around 96 when I tested...

```
.job_api <- function(page = 0){
  library(stringi)
  library(httr)
  # site url
  # 
  url <- "https://jf8q26wwud-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?"
  # They put request headers into their query string directly
  string_heads <- c(
    "x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20vanilla%20JavaScript%20(lite)%203.24.5%3Binstantsearch.js%201.6.0%3BJS%20Helper%202.21.2",
    "x-algolia-application-id=JF8Q26WWUD",
    "x-algolia-api-key=M2UzZmI1Zjc1NGMwZmYzZjJiNWE0ZTgxMzNjNmIzMjc2ODEyZWQwZTJmYzNjMDhjNmU3NGQ3ZGViMzJiZTlkNHRhZ0ZpbHRlcnM9JnVzZXJUb2tlbj00ODBiNjRhNzI2NjQ3ODgwMThmNDhjZWNkYmVhNGVlYg%3D%3D"
  )

  api_url <- stri_join(c(url, stri_join(string_heads, collapse = "&")), collapse = "")

  # form body data
  body_part <- '{"requests":[{"indexName":"vnw_job_v2","params":"query=&hitsPerPage=50&maxValuesPerFacet=20&page=0&restrictSearchableAttributes=%5B%22jobTitle%22%2C%22skills%22%2C%22company%22%5D&facets=%5B%22categoryIds%22%2C%22locationIds%22%2C%22categories%22%2C%22locations%22%2C%22skills%22%2C%22jobLevel%22%2C%22company%22%5D&tagFilters="}]}'
  # replace the body of the form data request with regex.. this is ugly but quick
  body_post <- stri_replace_all_regex(body_part, "(?<=page\\=)[0-9]+", page)

  # Make the api call
  call <- POST(api_url, body = body_post)
  # if pass... return data or else fail with the response information
  if(status_code(call) == 200L){
    content(call)
  }else {
    return(call)
  }

}
```

And here is what some of the outputs look like.

```
> test <- .job_api(0)
> length(test$results[[1]]$hits)
[1] 50
> names(test$results[[1]]$hits[[50]]$`_highlightResult`)
[1] "jobTitle"       "skills"         "company"        "jobDescription" "jobRequirement"
> test$results[[1]]$hits[[5]]$`_highlightResult`$skills[[1]]
$value
[1] "Process System Engineering"

$matchLevel
[1] "none"

$matchedWords
list()
```

Comment: Thank Mr Carl Boneri.

Comment: Thank Mr Carl Boneri. Your code is working well. I am wondering whether there is a limit about data that website allow an user to get via API?

Comment: My guess is 5000 records per session or something. Remember this is their internal API. So don't crush it.